# mysqldump: Couldn't find table: "|"

Tags: mysql, expect

I try to execute exp file:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

# mysql credentials and connection data
current_db_name='webui_dev'
new_db_name='db_2013'
db_host='localhost'
db_user='root'
db_pass=''


# using a here-document to pass commands to expect. 
# (the commands could be stored in a file as well)
expect <<EOF
  log_user 0
  spawn mysqldump -h "$db_host" -u "$db_user" -p "$current_db_name" | mysql -h "$db_host" -u "$db_user" -p "$new_db_name"
  expect "password:"
  send "$db_pass\r"
  log_user 1
  expect eof
EOF
```

I execute if with `-f` flag, and I get an error: `mysqldump: Couldn't find table: "|"`

if I try this approach

```
exp_internal 1
  spawn sh -c  "mysqldump -h \"$db_host\" -u \"$db_user\" -p \"$current_db_name\" | mysql -h \"$db_host\" -u \"$db_user\" -p \"$new_db_name\" "
```

I get an output

```
expect: option requires an argument -- f
usage: expect [-div] [-c cmds] [[-f] cmdfile] [args]
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {81914}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "password:"? no

expect: does "Enter password: " (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "password:"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "password:"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp7"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Enter password:"
send: sending "\r" to { exp7 }

Enter password: expect: timed out
```

Comment: `spawn` doesn't run the command through a shell, so it's treating `|` as a literal argument, not a shell pipeline.

Comment: is there any workarounds?.

Comment: Yes, run the command through a shell.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I generate this file programambly, and execute it programambly. So nee to expect an password prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Johannes is saying use a shell, he means:

```
  spawn sh -c "mysqldump -h \"$db_host\" -u \"$db_user\" -p \"$current_db_name\" | mysql -h \"$db_host\" -u \"$db_user\" -p \"$new_db_name\""
```

Comment: now it prompts for password (( `Enter password:` ignoring my `expect "password:"`

Comment: Add `exp_internal 1` after `log_user` to have expect show you why the match fails.

Comment: I added this output to my question!

Comment: The pattern matched, you sent an empty password, mysql didn't accept it and is re-prompting for the valid password.

Answer (score 1):

mysqldump commands takes parameter as you given and after database name it expect table name to be there

so it is assuming **|** is a table name

```
mysqldump [options] db_name [tbl_name ...]
```

updated answer

in order to dump a set of one or more tables,

```
shell> mysqldump [options] db_name [tbl_name ...]
```

a set of one or more complete databases

```
shell> mysqldump [options] --databases db_name ...
```

or an entire MySQL server—as shown here:

```
shell> mysqldump [options] --all-databases
```

Comment: I need to dump entire database, not table! And it isn't expecting there to be a table name if you run it in bash. This is an issue only fro exp. `mysqldump -h [server] -u [user] -p[password] db1 | mysql -h [server] -u [user] -p[password] db2` is the standard solution for db cloning!

Comment: use --database before dbname. for more check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: Ok.. But this isn't an issue.. Try `mysqldump -h [server] -u [user] -p[password] db1 | mysql -h [server] -u [user] -p[password] db2` yourself. I use it for many years, and I know that this command works.

Comment: yes it works, if my answer does not solver your problem then we both lookup for a solution. just try and let me know

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac I used this command:

```
mysqldump -u root -p [database_name] > /Users/rgavila/Documents/_WSCenter/Backup-Jul-5-2021.sql
```

It was as simple as including a chevron (>) to push out the file where I wanted it.

The screen went silent as it went to work.